# No sound from front headphone jack on MSI TRX40 Pro WiFi

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones

I'm trying to get sound working from the front headphone jack in Ubuntu 20.04 on an MSI TRX40 Pro WiFi. The motherboard has a slightly wonky setup where the audio apparently comes from a USB audio device, so it shows up in the various mixers (alsamixer, the Sound panel in Settings) as "USB Audio". When headphones are plugged in, the system correctly detects that they are plugged in, but no sound comes out of the headphones.

From searching around on Google, I found advice to disable auto-mute in alsamixer, but alsamixer doesn't have that option listed at all.

The really interesting thing is that I *can* get audio from the headphone jack by selecting the right device using `aplay`. The devices found by `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: ALC1220VBDT [ALC1220-VB-DT], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: ALC1220VBDT [ALC1220-VB-DT], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: ALC1220VBDT [ALC1220-VB-DT], device 2: USB Audio [USB Audio #2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: ALC1220VBDT [ALC1220-VB-DT], device 3: USB Audio [USB Audio #3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

[Ignore the HDMI audio; that's the GPU's audio support, which does actually work -- as long as I want to play sound out of the monitor speakers]

If I choose audio device hw:1,1 I can get aplay to play a wav file and hear it through the headphones on the front jack:

`aplay -Dhw:1,1 a2002011001-e02.wav`

So if I could somehow get the various systemwide mixers to use `hw:1,1` as their output everything would work fine (I think).

I saw that this chipset has some issues in Linux, and read through [this (long) kernel bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206873). So maybe all this would be fixed by using the `topic/usb-trx40` branch of https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/ ? But I'm hesitant to go that route if there's a simple way to get it working here.

**Summary: front panel sound works if I manually select the right device using `aplay -D`, can't figure out how to get any other mixer to use that device.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this with the following combination of ALSA, PulseAudio, and kernel patches:

1. ALSA: https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-ucm-conf/pull/25 . I didn't rebuild the package, I just dropped the two new files in `/usr/share/alsa/ucm2/USB-Audio/`.
2. PulseAudio: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/merge_requests/292 . I used `apt-get source pulseaudio` to get the source, applied the patch, and then used `dpkg-source --commit` to tell dpkg about the patch info. Then I rebuilt the pulseaudio packages with `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot` and installed them.
3. The `topic/usb-trx40` branch of this kernel tree: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/log/?h=topic/usb-trx40 . This is slightly tricky because I'm using ZFS, so I had to apply the ZFS patches as well as documented here: https://forum.level1techs.com/t/building-custom-kernel-with-zfs-built-in/117464

I'm not completely certain that all three are necessary, but they are sufficient. Sound works now!

Comment: Hey Brendan, thanks for the steps, I did 1 and 2 and got the headphones on my TRX40 Designare to work on kernel 5.8, but it gives me a lot of popping and cracking every second when playing a YouTube video, it works totally fine for you?

Comment: Yes, I don't hear any popping or crackling. Maybe the kernel patches are necessary after all?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually managed to make it work by changing the fragments and fragment size in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf. I also got very high latency using PulseEffects so in the end I just gave up that, better to have video and audio in sync I think

Comment: @Ronny: Would you share your /etc/pulse/daemon.conf file?

Comment: avoid-resampling = false
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 48000
alternate-sample-rate = 44100
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right

default-fragments = 8
default-fragment-size-msec = 4

deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1

Comment: Had the same problem. For me only the first step was enough: just copy these two files to the above mentioned location: https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-ucm-conf/pull/25/files?file-filters%5B%5D=#diff-c90d1eddf433cec8a46e77ebfafa0a1de2ff93b95a74c24a4acf3823d69646e5